# Does Haskell have a combination of `when` and `unless`?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm developing a TCP client that fetch a specified kind message from the streams and just find my self use a lot of unless and when expressions. For example:

```
hunt :: Socket -> ThreadId -> IO ()                               
hunt conn t = do threadDelay 1000000
                 msg <- recv conn 1024
                 unless (C.isInfixOf "1b14010102" $ encode msg) $ hunt conn t
                 when (C.isInfixOf "1b14010102" $ encode msg) $ do
                     threadDelay 7000000
                     sendAll conn $ goHunt
                     msg <- recv conn 1024
                     threadDelay 3000000
                     close conn
                     killThread t
```

I was trying to build a helper like:

```
waitfor :: ByteString -> Socket -> t -> (ByteString -> Socket -> t -> IO ()) -> IO ()
waitfor str conn tid f = do 
    threadDelay 1000000
    msg <- recv conn 1024
    let m = C.isInfixOf str msg
    unless m $ waitfor str conn tid f
    when m $ f msg conn tid
```

Then I can re-use the helper:

```
main = do
    ...
    tid <- myThreadId
    conn <- joinWorld u
    waitfor "1b14010102" conn tid hunt.
```

But if I have another function (it take 3 arguments unlike `hunt`)

```
hunt' :: ByteString -> Socket -> ThreadId -> IO ()
hunt' idx conn t = do threadDelay 1000000
                      msg <- recv conn 1024
                      unless (C.isInfixOf "0300aa0801" $ encode msg) $ hunt' conn t
                      when (C.isInfixOf "0300aa0801" $ encode msg) $ do
                          threadDelay 1000000
                          sendAll conn $ goHunt' idx
                          threadDelay 3000000
                          close conn
                          killThread t
```

then I can't use `waitfor`, and need to use `when`/`unless` again. So, does Haskell have a combination of `when`/`unless`? If not, then what is a better approach for my case?

Comment: The pattern you have is `foo = in do { ..; if something then foo else .. }`. That is the pattern you should abstract into its own function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Why can't you use `waitfor`? Couldn't you write `hunt'` as `hunt' idx conn t = waitfor "0300aa0801" conn t $ do {  ... your do-block from your original hunt' goes here ... }`?

Comment: Hi David Young, your answer works for my case. I can modify `waitfor` and use the way you've suggested. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

You can just use `if ... then ... else` for that.

For example,

```
waitfor :: ByteString -> Socket -> t -> (ByteString -> Socket -> t -> IO ()) -> IO ()
waitfor str conn tid f = do 
    threadDelay 1000000
    msg <- recv conn 1024
    if C.isInfixOf str msg
    then waitfor str conn tid f
    else f msg conn tid
```

Comment: Thank for your response, but still can't apply the helper function for other functions like hunt' ?

Comment: if you include the code for `hunt'`, someone might be able to help you find a helper that works for both.

Comment: Why can't you use `hunt'` in an `if` expression?

Comment: @T.Do Maybe you can give a specific example of what thing (or things) you're trying to do that aren't working